# "render_existing" -- how to return html from "view" from 'shared/sub_template1.html'?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my base layout I have this:

```
  <%= render_existing(@view_module, "sub_template1." <> @view_template, assigns) %>
```

which I want to render only on certain pages. I have "shared/sub_template1.html.eex" subtemplate for that purpose and I want to render it at "articles/index". Thus I have this:

```
defmodule MyApp.ArticleView do
   #....

  def render("sub_template1.index.html", _assigns) do
#    var1 = "something"
#    var2 = "something2"
#    render("shared/sub_template1.html", var1: "var1", var2: "var2") #doesn't work! exception!


# this works -- rendering html manually
# but I don't want this
raw """
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    #{var1} #{var2}
  <!-- ............... -->

"""
```

I want to render -- read and return -- html from "shared/sub_template1.html" instead of returning html manually from MyApp.ArticleView/render. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have `MyApp.SharedView` defined? Try defining an empty `SharedView` and then use `render(MyApp.SharedView, "sub_template1.html", var1: "var1", var2: "var2")`.

Comment: @Dogbert `render(MyApp.SharedView, "sub_template1.html", var1: "var1", var2: "var2")` ----> where at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot render a template from another folder by just passing a path with `/`. In order to render `web/templates/shared/sub_template1.html.eex` (note: if the file ends with `.html`, you'll also have to change that to `.html.eex`), you'll have to create a View named `MyApp.SharedView`:

```
# web/views/shared_view.ex
defmodule MyApp.SharedView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view
end
```

Then, in `ArticleView`, add this:

```
def render("sub_template1.index.html", _assigns) do
  var1 = "something"
  var2 = "something2"
  render(MyApp.SharedView, "sub_template1.html", var1: var1, var2: var2)
end
```

Comment: If I had multiple "render_existing" in application.html.eex -- "sub_nav1", "sub2", "sub3",  how would I go about  rendering them all  in my ArticleView ?

Comment: If I had multiple "render_existing" in application.html.eex -- "sub_nav1", "sub2", "sub3", how would I go about rendering them all in my ArticleView ?

Comment: You can create `def render("sub_nav1.index.html", _assigns) do`, `def render("sub2.index.html", _assigns) do`, etc?